# How to use mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

In my application, I have links like this:domain.com/forum/cat.php?id=15&page=16
I want to rewrite them to domain.com/forum/cat/string/15/page/16

The string part in it is just a random text with no importance. How should I do this in mod rewrite?

Comment: You could look up some examples. Look up how you use it. Try some things. First toss them into .htaccess to test them out, then if you like them, push them into the apache directive files themselves.

Comment: I tried reading a lot of tutorials online but I just can't get it to work. I'll continue trying anyway.

Comment: Well the thing is... we need to see what you have tried, what isn't working out right for you, seeing some examples of what you have, what you want, what its doing. Otherwise its too broad of a question to really help on the issue you got.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the right combination:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/cat/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/page/([0-9]+) forum/cat.php?id=$2&page=$3 [NC]
```

Comment: Clever. I've never seen rewrite used query parameters before. Nicely done.